# Need help fixing an algorithm that approximates pi

Tags: c, optimization, pi, approximation

I'm trying to write the C code for an algorithm that approximates **pi**. It's supposed to get the volume of a cube and the volume of a sphere inside that cube (the sphere's radius is 1/2 of the cube's side). Then I am supposed to divide the cube's volume by the sphere's and multiply by 6 to get pi.

It's working but it's doing something weird in the part that is supposed to get the volumes. I figure it's something to do the with delta I chose for the approximations.
With a cube of side 4 instead of giving me a volume of 64 it's giving me 6400. With the sphere instead of 33 it's giving me 3334. something.

Can someone figure it out? Here is the code (I commented the relevant parts):

```
#include <stdio.h>      

int in_esfera(double x, double y, double z, double r_esfera){
    double dist = (x-r_esfera)*(x-r_esfera) + (y-r_esfera)*(y-r_esfera) + (z-r_esfera)*(z-r_esfera);

    return  dist <= (r_esfera)*(r_esfera) ? 1 : 0;   
}   

double get_pi(double l_cubo){   
    double r_esfera = l_cubo/2;   
    double total = 0;
    double esfera = 0;    
//this is delta, for the precision. If I set it to 1E anything less than -1 the program continues endlessly. Is this normal?
    double delta = (1E-1);   

    for(double x = 0; x < l_cubo; x+=delta){
        printf("x => %f; delta => %.6f\n",x,delta);
        for(double y = 0; y <l_cubo; y+=delta){
            printf("y => %f; delta => %.6f\n",y,delta);
            for(double z = 0; z < l_cubo; z+=delta){
                printf("z => %f; delta => %.6f\n",z,delta);
                total+=delta;
                if(in_esfera(x,y,z,r_esfera))
                    esfera+=delta;
            }
        }
    }

    //attempt at fixing this
        //esfera/=delta;
        //total/=delta;
    //

//This printf displays the volumes. Notice how the place of the point is off. If delta isn't a power of 10 the values are completely wrong.   
    printf("v_sphere = %.8f; v_cube = %.8f\n",esfera,total);   

    return (esfera)/(total)*6;
}   

void teste_pi(){        
    double l_cubo = 4;    
    double pi = get_pi(l_cubo);

    printf("%.8f\n",pi);
}   

int main(){   
    teste_pi();
}
```

Comment: Your `get_pi` function is like `O((l_cubo / delta)**3)` (_cubic_ complexity! No wonder it "continues endlessly"). Is it supposed to calculate the volumes of the cube & the sphere?

Comment: @ForceBru Partly. First that's what it does yes (check the last printf on that function) and then returns the ratio * 6 (or pi).

Comment: Turns out, you need to _multiply_ both volumes by `(delta * delta)`, like `esfera *= delta * delta;` to fix this. It's simple math, but I'm not quite sure how to put it into words lol

Comment: @ForceBru That works even when delta isn't a power of 10. Thanks! I'm curious as to why it works...

Comment: @ForceBru they could have picked square and circle, if they meant to reduce time complexity. Also, seems to slightly lower error.

Comment: Additionally, the precision could be seriously improved by not using double or floating point, but int (or maybe even long long) wherever possible. Instead of having double delta and double l_cubo, use double *only* when returning pi(and the division where pi is calculated). Otherwise you are adding up precision errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing is that multiplication *over integers* like `a * b * c` is the same as adding `1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + ... + 1` `a * b * c` times, right?

You're adding `delta + delta + ...` `(x / delta) * (y / delta) * (z / delta)` times. Or, in other words, `(x * y * z) / (delta ** 3)` times.

Now, that sum of `delta`s is the same as this:

```
delta * (1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + ...)
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ (x * y * z) / (delta**3) times
```

So, if `delta` is a power of 10, `(x * y * z) / (delta**3)` will be an integer, and it'll be equal to the sum of 1's in parentheses (because it's the same as the *product* `x * y * (z / (delta**3))`, where the last term is an integer - see the very first sentence of this answer). Thus, your result will be the following:

```
delta * ( (x * y * z) / (delta ** 3) ) == (x * y * z) / (delta**2)
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the sum of ones
```

That's how you ended up calculating the product *divided by `delta` squared*.

To solve this, multiply all volumes by `delta * delta`.

---

However, I don't think it's possible to use this logic for `delta`s that aren't a power of 10. And indeed, the code will go all kinds of haywire for `delta == 0.21` and `l_cubo == 2`, for example: you'll get `9.261000000000061` instead of 8.

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> total+=delta;
> if(in_esfera(x,y,z,r_esfera))
>     esfera+=delta;
> ```

`total` and `esfera` are three-dimensional volumes whereas `delta` is a one-dimensional length. If you were tracking units you'd have *m<sup>3</sup>* on the left and *m* on the right. The units are incompatible.

To fix it, cube `delta` so that you're conceptually accumulating tiny cubes instead of tiny lines.

```
total+=delta*delta*delta;
if(in_esfera(x,y,z,r_esfera))
    esfera+=delta*delta*delta;
```

Doing that fixes the output, and also works for any value of `delta`:

```
v_sphere = 33.37400000; v_cube = 64.00000000
3.12881250
```

Note that this algorithm "works" for arbitrary `delta` values, but it has severe accuracy issues. It's incredibly prone to rounding problems. It works best when `delta` is a power of two: `1/64.0` is better than `1/100.0`, for example:

```
v_sphere = 33.50365448; v_cube = 64.00000000
3.14096761
```

Also, if you want your program to run faster get rid of all those printouts! Or at least the ones in the inner loops...